# How can I use a function in server.R using R, shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, plyr

everyone: How can I design a function in server.R and use it?. Another question is: how can I get the values from a reactive object?
For example, here is my code:

```
  datatable <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
     if (is.null(inFile))
    return(NULL)
  read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep, quote=input$quote)
  })
```

So, here, datatable is a reactive object storing a data.frame from the .csv file. When I do like datatable(), it can be used like a data.frame. But how can I get the data.frame from it? I tried data <- datatable(), it did not work.

Another question is about my code below:

```
  output$singletable <- renderDataTable({
    a <- subset(datatable(),!is.na(datatable()$actualfailureyear))
    b <- count(a,c(input$sfactor))
    c1 <- datatable()[!duplicated(datatable()$AssetID),]
    c <- ddply(.data = c1,.variables = input$sfactor,function(x){sum(x$length)})
    d <- merge(b,c,by=input$sfactor)
    e <- ddply(.data = d,.variables = input$sfactor,function(x){data.frame(failcount=x$freq,length=x$V1,failrate=x$freq/(x$V1*0.00001)/21)})
  })
```

I will use the code a-e all the time, so I really need to put them into a function and use is anywhere I want. Could you please show me how to do it with more details?

Another thing that I do not understand is about the two lines of c and e. When I do like c <- aggregate(length~input$sfactor,c1,sum), it turned to be an error. The same thing happened when I used transform() for e. But now it is working well. So my question is: what is the difference between ddply and aggregate/transform. In this case, they generate the exact same result.

Thanks a lot everyone.

Comment: I was about to comment the same thing. OP has posted 3-4 questions in the last 24 hours, which are small parts of the same app, and hasn't accepted any answers.

Comment: I suggest you to ask one question per post to make it more readable and to get more help.  Please go through introductory page of how to ask a good question at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sorry guys. This is my first time to use stackoverflow although I joined here months ago. I just realized how to accept the answers after you remined me of this. Yeah, I am trying to do an app. But I just started using shiny so that I got a lot of issues. I already accepted the answers. That do help me so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figure this out.
I design a function and put it outside of shinyserver:

```
pickedsinglefactor <- function(singlefactor,datatable){
    #processing
 }
```

In shinyserver, I use

```
s <- reactive(pickedsinglefactor(sfactor,datatable))
```

for using the function. Now s is a reactive object including a data.frame. Then I can use it